# Why are trigonometric functions considered rational?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, trigonometry

So I am reading spivaks calculus and in it he states that a rational function is a function of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomial functions and $q$ is not the function that is always equal to $0$ however he then states that the function $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$
Is rational .

How can this be?

How is $\sin(x^2)$ the ratio of 2 polynomials?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not rational.

Comment: The statemen, as reported here, is not true.

Comment: Where exactly is that statement? Edition and page number?

Comment: Spivak says he is considering a larger class of functions than just rational functions. I think you did not read the sentence before these examples properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of this seems to be the bottom of [page 42](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Calculus/7JKVu_9InRUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=spivak%20calculus&pg=PA42&printsec=frontcover). But I think you're misinterpreting Spivak. The relevant passage is this:

"The rational functions are themselves quite special examples of an even larger class of functions, very thoroughly studied in calculus, which are simpler than many of the functions first mentioned in this chapter. The following are examples of this kind of function:"

Spivak then goes on to enumerate a few examples, including $\sin(x^2)$. However, Spivak is *not* claiming that these examples are rational but rather that they're examples of an "even larger class of functions". On the next page, he clarifies that he's talking about functions which can be produced by composition of simpler functions. In the present case, one has $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$ as the composition $f(x)=g(h(x))$ where $g(x)=\sin x$ and $h(x)=x^2$. Every rational function can be generated using such compositions, but Spivak's examples are certainly not rational.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$ is rational. Then there are polynomials $p,q$ as above such that $\sin (x^2)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}.$ By continuity we get

$$p(x)=q(x) \sin (x^2)$$

for all $x$. Now let $x_n:= \sqrt{n \pi}$  for $n \in \mathbb N.$ Then we have

$$p(x_n)=0$$

for all $n$. But  the set of zeros of $p$ is finite, a contradiction.